# How compatible is the Java implementation of Android exactly?

Tags: java, android

Is there any definition that states which standard class libraries are supported on Android?

Let's assume we build a jar library and compile it using JavaSE.
This library will maybe used by a JavaSE server application and/or on a JSP Server.

Are there any means to know beforehand if Androids dex will be able to compile this Library into Dalvik bytecode?
Other means than Trial&Error i mean :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZDNet has a [comparison](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/java-vs-android-apis/504), but it's from the RC days of Android 1.0 (early 2008). Comparing ZDNet's "not supported" list with the current [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) and [Java SE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/overview-summary.html) docs, there appear to be a few changes:

- java.applet: unsupported
- **java.awt: partial (a couple of classes in java.awt.font)**
- **java.beans: partial**
- java.lang.management: unsupported
- java.rmi: unsupported
- javax.accessibility: unsupported
- javax.activity: unsupported
- javax.imageio: unsupported
- javax.management: unsupported
- javax.naming: unsupported
- javax.print: unsupported
- javax.rmi: unsupported
- javax.security.auth.kerberos: unsupported
- javax.security.auth.spi: unsupported
- javax.security.sasl: unsupported
- javax.swing: unsupported
- javax.transaction: unsupported
- **javax.xml (except javax.xml.parsers): partial (missing bind, crypto, soap, stream, transform.stax, ws)**
- org.ietf.*: unsupported
- org.omg.*: unsupported
- **org.w3c.dom.* (sub-packages): partial (missing bootstrap, events, some classes in ls)**

Also note that Android bundles some non Java SE APIs (jUnit, HttpClient, JSON, etc).

Answer (score 6):

You can look at the [Android class library](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) and make sure you only use classes and methods that are listed there.

However, there is no substitute for actually trying it.

Comment: Just thought it would be nice to be able to restrict the classpath of a cross-plattform library to a certain set of class libraries. Otherwise each change may introduce android specific compile-time errors. Therefore each change has to be compiled on Android first which may result in a cumbersome development process.