# How to use ipp(Internet Printing Protocol) with HTTP to print file in android?

Tags: java, android, printing, ipp-protocol

I want to print file from android application.For the same , after searching on google,I found some useful information that i will have to use IPP (Internet Printing Protocol) with HTTP. And I am new to ipp but i have worked with HTTP.
So can anybody help me for the same ?
Can anybody give me some useful information OR links?
Thanks in advance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an HTTP PUT request with some special features, you must:

- use the port 631 instead of 80 (unless it's explicitly specified of course).
- rewrite the url in the header (i.e. `ipp:// => http://`).
- protocol ID is `IPP/1.1`.
- you must authenticate via a challenge method.

OTOH, the request/response format used in the body is binary, so you should really really read the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2910.txt). Besides that, it's quite simple, all you need is job and printer URIs, and then you just send properly encoded data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Can you give me hint how to make request using header ipp:// in android as i only have ip address of printer ?

Comment: that's all you need, `ipp://ip:631` in the body and `http://ip:631` in the HTTP header... just open a socket and start writing...

Comment: Is there any link to get sample code to make above request ? Because I am not able to code to open socket in android.Can you please give me such information ?

Comment: Is it correct code for me ?http://www.android10.org/index.php/forums/46-networking-a-database/1688-android-socket-program-java-to-print-to-tcpip-printer

Comment: If you don't care about compatibility, using a CGI could be a good idea.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the `gnu.javax.print.IppPrintService` class. It may or may not work on Android... I've had no chance to try it.

Comment: gnu.javax.print.IppPrintService is not available in android.Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6027/discussion-between-ramesh-solanki-and-ismael)

Comment: Is it correct code ?  http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Apache-Harmony-Java-SE/org-package/org.apache.harmony.x.print.ipp.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this sample http://code.google.com/p/jspi/source/browse/trunk/jspi/src/main/java/de/lohndirekt/print/examples/SimpleDocExample.java. It is a Java library for IPP.

Comment: jspi is based on javax.print which is unsupported on android:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418530/how-compatible-is-the-java-implementation-of-android-exactly/4419657#4419657

Answer (score 0):

Using [ipp-client-kotlin](https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-client-kotlin) printing a file can be implemented like this:

```
IppPrinter("ipp://colorjet.local/ipp/printer")
    .printJob(File("A4-blank.pdf"))
    .waitForTermination()
```