# Is there a way to send a print task to an IPP-enabled network printer using http?

Tags: android, http, printing, ipp-protocol

I'm working on an Android print service application which is supposed to allow the user to do the following: browse through the phone's internal storage and send the selected file to an IPP-enabled printer to print.

I've combed the net for the past few days, but i've only found one solution [[How to use ipp(Internet Printing Protocol) with HTTP to print file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570882/how-to-use-ippinternet-printing-protocol-with-http-to-print-file-in-android/8571334#8571334]) that somewhat makes sense to me. However, i've no idea how to go on from here on, besides knowing that a http put request must be made to the printer's url. Any help? Thanks

Note: the Google Cloud Print is NOT an option for me.

Comment: If you're a student: study RFCs and start coding :-) - in case "you are a company" and look for a solution: contact me or add contact information to your profile.

Answer (score 0):

As starting point you should

- read the [IPP Implementor's Guide](http://ftp.pwg.org/pub/pwg/candidates/cs-ippig20-20150821-5100.19.pdf)
- implement [IPP encoding and transport](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2910)
- have a good understanding of [IPP model and semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2911)

**Update 2023**

With [ipp-client](https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-client-kotlin) you can submit PDFs to IPP network printers from Android:

```kotlin
IppPrinter("ipp://colorjet.local")
   .printJob(File("my.pdf"), documentFormat("application/pdf"))
   .waitForTermination()
```

If the printer does not support PDF you need to transform the document into a format supported by the printer.

Comment: hi. as a matter of fact, i did. however, every http/ipp request i've made either returns either one of these errors: 1) bad request 2)broken pipe.

Comment: the ipp communication is not working correct. either the ipp-server doesn't conform to the spec, or your ipp-client is doing something wrong (more likely). "bad request" means the ipp-server can't interpret the ipp-request you've encoded. you could also use a thirdparty library e.g. from ipp-software.com.

Comment: Something I haven't seen mentioned is byte order. If you're on a PC, you need to do the C# equivalent of htons/ntohs.