# iOS printing with IPP Printer

Tags: ios, objective-c, snmp, bonjour, ipp-protocol

Currently, I can search my printer with `Bonjour/SNMP` protocol by

```
NSNetServiceBrowser
NSNetService
```

Now I want to print my document by IPP protocol.

Could you please tell me way to print with IPP in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually iOS Apps don't care about the printer protocol. It's sufficient to use [Apples AirPrint focused Print-API](https://developer.apple.com/airprint/). I can't see how UIPrinter would expose details like IPP connections through the API.

If you don't want to use Apples API for printing, you should [implement IPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445325/is-there-a-way-to-send-a-print-task-to-an-ipp-enabled-network-printer-using-http). A good start could be to look at my [simple print-job implementation written in java](https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-printjob-java/blob/master/src/main/java/ipp/PrintJob.java). I'd be happy to assist in porting this to Swift of Objectiv C.

Comment: In fact AirPrint is based on IPP. The print API hides all details of the protocol though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually iOS applications doesn't bothered about printing protocols.We can print images and other documents using apples AirPrint. The steps for printing from iOS device described below.

1.Connect our device and printer in the same network.

2.select an image/document for printing.

3.select the printer from network.

4.Give print

We can give print from gallery,chrome etc and other printing applications.In android we need print plugins for printing(eg:Mopria, a universal print plugin).
But in iOS we don't need the support of any plugins, i think.