# Show non-AirPrint compatible printers in iOS with Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working on an application allowing the management of printers (add, modify, delete, etc.) with Swift 5. The added printers are stored in the application (@AppStorage). The printers in question use the TCP/IP and ARP protocol. They are not AirPrint compatible and are therefore not visible in the list of printers in iOS.

I want to make them available in iOS so that I can print from any application (Photos, File, Safari, etc.).

***Note: the printers are not only not AirPrint compatible but are not equipped with bluetooth either.***

Assuming that the printers are already discovered on the network, how can I do this?

Comment: I don’t know how to answer you question but don’t limit your searches to SwiftUI. Connecting to a network printer wouldn’t have anything to do with SwiftUI

Comment: "The printers in question use the TCP/IP and ARP protocol." Surely it also knows IPP? In any case, you would need to implement the protocol yourself. [Here are some starting points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37376494/5133585).

Comment: iOS can only print natively to airprint printers. You can't add non-AirPrint printers. You could, perhaps, implement a share extension in your app that allowed users to send documents to your app to be printed, but this is likely to be pretty limited in the sort of data you can receive